# How many clock cycles does casting a bit vector take?

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to rework a bit vector algorithm into using floats instead of integers. Sounds absurd, but the idea is to then use AVX optimisations, which for many current processors would allow four times the amount of data to be processed at the same time.

Now floats are lacking |, & and ^ operations, so I thought that possibly I had to interpret the bitvectors as integers to apply these operations. (And hopefully still get enough speed up from the rest of the algorithm.)

Clarification: I basically want to apply |,^,& to doubles. I know that those are a structured data type and that these operations don't have any meaning for floating point numbers. I know that the bit fiddling will probably have to be restricted to the significand. I know that it is difficult to control the shifts of the floating point (I'll probably need some leading zeroes.). I don't know anything about assembly language. The whole point is using the [larger parallelism/throughput in floating point SIMD calculations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#Applications).

My question is how to do this in the best way and whether it would be feasible in terms of speed. (After all I'm competing with the original integer based algorithm.)

Given that I'm a relative noob in C programming, I'm also thankful for general advice concerning this endeavour.

Edit: The code would probably run on Ivy or Sandy Bridge processors.

Further explanation:
Let's say the original algorithm has this step:

X <- A + B

Now I recreate this step with doubles, by being careful that the exponent equals zero and that there is a leading zero after the implied first zero.

X <- A + B - 1.0

In that case the last 51 bits of my doubles's mantissa undergo the same process as the 64 bits of the original integers. The difference being, that I can do it for four data points at the same time. I.e. 204 bits instead of 64 (Ok, it's two operations, so maybe just 102 bits). 
But the next step demands X <- A | B, or A & B, or A ^ B …
What to do?

Of course there could be any number of misconceptions and errors in this concept. After all it is a pretty complicated idea of a relative beginner.

Comment: You should show some code, at least the relevant parts of the operations you're interested in. Does AVX have *any* relevant instructions? Also, asking for cycle counts without specifying a processor or exact code makes the question very hard to answer.

Comment: There are bitwise operations on floats in the AVX instruction set so you don't even have to convert anything.

Comment: That sound more than weird. A float is a structured datatype, while bitops operate on a bitfield. so  `1.5 & 4e-7` just makes no sense.

Comment: Why don't you use embedded assembly instead? That will be way easier to implement.

Comment: Wait, you're going to emulate integers in doubles? That makes no sense. Just use SSE4 then.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the VORPS, VANDPS, and VXORPS instructions, which are precisely bitwise or, and, and xor on AVX vectors?  There's no need to restrict to the 52 bit significand or play any other funny games; although these instructions are in the floating-point domain, they are just bitwise operations on 256b vectors.  You are *way* over-complicating this.

Comment: Well. I guess I come up with ideas based on very limited knowledge. ;-) I will take a look into some assembler book or something. Thanks!